# IOError: cannot identify image file when loading images from pdf files

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, wand

I am trying to read scanned images from a pdf using **wand** and display it using **PIL**. But I get some error. First page of the pdf file works perfectly but the second page shows this error.

Code

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display
from PIL import Image as PI
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders
import io
import numpy as np
import cStringIO
tool = pyocr.get_available_tools()[0]
lang = tool.get_available_languages()[1]
req_image = []
final_text = []
image_pdf = Image(filename="DEEP_PLAST_20.700.pdf", resolution=200)
image_jpeg = image_pdf.convert('jpeg')
img_page = Image(image=image_jpeg.sequence[1])
img_buffer = np.asarray(bytearray(img_page.make_blob()), dtype=np.uint8)
print(img_buffer)
# im = PI.fromarray(img_buffer)
im = PI.open(cStringIO.StringIO(img_buffer))
```

I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ocr.py", line 43, in <module>
    im = PI.open(cStringIO.StringIO(img_buffer))
  File "/home/sahil/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2452, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file <cStringIO.StringI object at 0x7fc4a8f168b0>
```

I don't why the code fails on the second page of the pdf whereas it works for the first one.

Any help would be appreciated!